# Content not from webpack is served from in react

Tags: reactjs

I just created one simple react app. after npm start nothing was served in the web browser.

**> firstapp@0.1.0 start E:\Projects\ReactProject\firstapp

> react-scripts start
> i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.43.128/
> i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
> i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from E:\Projects\ReactProject\firstapp\public
> i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /**

Answer (score 0):

Hi I need more information on your file structure because simply having Webpack with loaders is not enough for setting up a server.

You could refer to some open source projects to see how they have set it up

https://github.com/sanyuan0704/react-cloud-music

Please let me now if you have the file structure. Thanks